# INNODB, mysql - foreign key to multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

say that I have a table A like that:

```
[my id (primary key) (auto increment)] [other values]
```

and another table B like that

```
[my id (primary key)] [id of the row in table A] [other values]
```

can I use the foreign key to link all the rows of table B to the unique row in the table A? The goal is to force the CANCEL to all rows in table B if that row in table A is deletet.

it would be possible to achieve the same result linking other tables similar to the B one, which contains multiple rows dependent of the unique row in table A?

I wasn't able to understand the guides in internet, so I ask here, where I know there are a lot of experts. thaks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about foreign key relationship in Mysql - innoDB tables.
Then yes if There is a table A having primary Key id

If this key is used as Foreign Key in Table B  and while specifying relationship in PhpMyAdmin Relation view of Table B. We need to specify ON DELETE CASCADE. So whenever a record in Table A will be deleted its corresponding child records in Table B will be deleted.

Comment: so there's no problem if more values of table B are linked to the key in table A. Now I have to try using phpMyAdmin to do so... if I am able...

Comment: It is very easy to do. go to structure of table B (for example). click Relation View in bottom. and in the new screen in front of foreign key select on delete cascade for both of the options.